# My app stopped on setContentView() on <= API 21

Tags: java, android

I have an app which works on API 24 perfectly, but on API <= 21 some activity crashes on setContentView(...) and some ones do work correcty

any help please?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:id="@+id/main"

    tools:context="com.......Bounds"
    >

    <LinearLayout
```

Comment: Stacktrace? Code? Full layout?

Answer (score 0):

Solved
the problem was using 
android:textDirection="firstStrongLtr"
witch not work on <= API 21